# boost continuation resume Assert failed

Tags: c++, boost

i try to test continuation, my code is below

```
ctx::continuation fc1; 
ctx::continuation fc2;

ctx::continuation foo1(ctx::continuation&& c) {
    LOG_DBUG("enter");
    c = c.resume();
    LOG_DBUG("done 1");
    fc2 = fc2.resume();
    LOG_DBUG("done 2");
    fc2 = fc2.resume();
    return std::move(c);
}

ctx::continuation foo2(ctx::continuation&& c) {
    LOG_DBUG("enter");
    c = c.resume();
    LOG_DBUG("done 1");
    fc1 = fc1.resume();
    LOG_DBUG("done 2");
    fc1 = fc1.resume();
    return std::move(c);
}


int main() {
    fc1 = ctx::callcc(foo1);
    fc2 = ctx::callcc(foo2);

    LOG_INFO("after callcc");

    for (;;) {
        while(fc1 = fc1.resume()) LOG_DBUG("main c1");
        while(fc2 = fc2.resume()) LOG_DBUG("main c2");
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

stdout got

DBUG [coepoll.cpp:36] [foo1]enter

DBUG [coepoll.cpp:46] [foo2]enter

INFO [coepoll.cpp:61] [main]after callcc

DBUG [coepoll.cpp:38] [foo1]done 1

DBUG [coepoll.cpp:48] [foo2]done 1

./myboost/include/boost/context/continuation_fcontext.hpp:263: boost::context::continuation boost::context::continuation::resume() &&: Assertion `nullptr != fctx_' failed.

Seems to at  function `foo2` call `fc1 = fc1.resume()` cause assert failed.
Is there some error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `resume` is called, `continuation` object is invalidated.

[Reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/cc.html) says:

> continuation is a one-shot continuation - it can be used only once,
>   after calling continuation::resume() or continuation::resume_with() it
>   is invalidated.

The following pseudocode shows how `resume` function works:

```
 foo(continutation&& mainContext) {
            mainContext = mainContext.resume(); 
     //                 | 
     //                 |   [2] resume is called;
     //                 |   [2] resume invalidates mainContext; 
     //                 |   [2] no return value is assigned to mainContext!
     //                 |   [2] we go back to main
     // [4]             |
     // make assignment |
     // now mainContext | 
     // is valid        |
 }

int main(){
    fooContext = callcc( foo );          // [1] we enter into foo function;
    fooContext = fooContext.resume();    // [3] we go back to foo 
}
```

---

Below is simplified version of your code, lets analyze it:

```
ctx::continuation foo1(ctx::continuation&& main) {
    main = main.resume(); // [2]
    fc2 = fc2.resume(); // [6]
    fc2 = fc2.resume();
    return std::move(c);
}

ctx::continuation foo2(ctx::continuation&& main) {
    main = main.resume(); // [4]
    fc1 = fc1.resume(); // [7]
    fc1 = fc1.resume();
    return std::move(c);
}


int main() {
    fc1 = ctx::callcc(foo1); // [1]
    fc2 = ctx::callcc(foo2); // [3]

    for (;;) {
        while(fc1 = fc1.resume()) LOG_DBUG("main c1"); // [5]
        while(fc2 = fc2.resume()) LOG_DBUG("main c2");
        break;
    }
```

1. `foo1` starts.
2. Execution returns to `main`.
3. `foo2` starts.
4. Execution returns to `main`.
5. `resume` is called on `fc1`. `fc1` is invalidated. Control execution returns to [6].
6. In this line execution in `foo2` is resumed, we jump to [7].
7. `resume` is called on **invalidated** `fc1`, program is aborted.

Comment: seeing somewhere，there are symmetric and asymmetric coroutines. I want to implement  a server frame  with epoll and use boost::callcc to switch on block io. so the callcc can only implement asymmetric scheduler?